# Motherboard bootup screen appears after waking computer up from sleep

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, sleep

I've recently built my first computer a couple weeks ago, and luckily everything worked with no issues.

For the first week or so, I would shut it down when I wasn't using it. A friend of mine told me that it was stressful on the hardware to do so, and recommended to use sleep mode if I planned on using it again soon. I took his advice and started using sleep mode. My power button's light would blink to signal that it was in sleep mode.

This changed a couple days ago when I noticed that the power button was no longer blinking. When I pressed the power button, I saw the motherboard bootup screen. Until this, I've only ever seen this screen when I turned the computer on. I thought at first that my power went out, but when I logged in, all of the programs that were running were still up. I tried to make sure that the computer never hibernated, although I could have missed a setting.

Does it sound like my computer isn't going into sleep mode? Is it weird that the motherboard screen appears after waking the computer up from 'sleep'? I know it seems like a paranoid question, but I just want to make sure that something weird isn't happening.

In case it might be helpful, my motherboard is MSI h110m gaming motherboard and I have Windows 10 installed.

Comment: Hi - it sounds like your computer had gone to hibernation rather than sleep. The difference is very subtle with sleep mode being the fastest option upon boot as it takes the information stored in RAM rather the hibernate which 'dumps' the RAM content into the hiberfil.sys file stored on the disk drive and shuts fully down and upon restart goes through most of the restart screens i.e. BIOS, dmi checks and so forth. In your case, open event viewer > System to see if any problems occurred between 'sleeping' the computer and restarting it and what potentially prevented the sleep mode.

Comment: @JimNielsen I did not know about the event viewer. Thanks! It says that it enters sleep mode and then returns from sleep mode, so I'm still puzzled about why I'm seeing the motherboard screen. There's a lot to look at here, so thanks again.